# merge chronological elements

Tags: python

I have a set of items that consists of the start and stop dates, as the following:

| ID | started | stop |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-01-14 | 2018-02-05 |
| 2 | 2019-01-14 | 2019-03-06 |
| 3 | 2019-03-07 | 2019-03-20-> |
| 4 | Some-Date | NULL |
| 5 | ***2020-09-08*** | 2020-09-14 |
| 6 | 2020-09-15 | ***2020-10-14*** |
| 7 | ->2019-03-21 | 2019-03-30 |

I would like to merge those item who share a chronological order from the order: elem.stop = nxtElem.started + 1

The result should look like:

| ID | started | stop |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-01-14 | 2018-02-05 |
| 2 | 2019-01-14 | 2019-03-30 |
| 3 | Some-Date | NULL |
| 4 | 2020-09-08 | 2020-10-14 |

I am currently checking the difference between each date, and if its one day then group them, however i am getting weird results

```
class Records:

    def __init__(self, start_dt, stop_dt):
        self.groupNum = None
        self.dayDiff = None
        self.start_dt = start_dt
        self.stop_dt = stop_dt

    def setGroupNum(self, groupNum):
        self.groupNum = groupNum


    def setdayDiff(self, dayDiff):
        self.dayDiff = dayDiff

def main():
    recordsLst = []
    resultLst = []

    recordsLst.append(Records(datetime.date(2017, 8, 14), datetime.date(2018, 3, 5)))
    recordsLst.append(Records(datetime.date(2019, 1, 14), datetime.date(2019, 3, 6)))
    recordsLst.append(Records(datetime.date(2019, 3, 7), datetime.date(2019, 3, 20)))
    recordsLst.append(Records(datetime.date(2023, 12, 30), datetime.date(9999, 12, 31)))
    recordsLst.append(Records(datetime.date(2020, 9, 8), datetime.date(2020, 9, 14)))
    recordsLst.append(Records(datetime.date(2020, 9, 15), datetime.date(2020, 10, 14)))
    recordsLst.append(Records(datetime.date(2019, 3, 21), datetime.date(2019, 3, 30)))
recordsLst .sort(key=lambda x: x.start_dt, reverse=False)
    for index, a in enumerate(recordsLst):
        for b in recordsLst[index:]:
            # If same item
            if (a.start_dt.day == b.start_dt.day and
                a.start_dt.month == b.start_dt.month and
                a.start_dt.year == b.start_dt.year) and \
                    (a.stop_dt.day == b.stop_dt.day and
                     a.stop_dt.month == b.stop_dt.month and
                     a.stop_dt.year == b.stop_dt.year):
                a.setGroupNum('same')
                # If in a chronological order
            if a.stop_dt.month == b.start_dt.month \
                    and a.stop_dt.year == b.start_dt.year \
                    and (a.stop_dt.day - b.start_dt.day) == -1:
                a.setdayDiff(-1)
                a.setGroupNum(index)
                resultLst.append(Datum(a.stop_dt, b.start_dt))
            else:
                a.setdayDiff(None)
            print(index, a, b)
```

New pandas dataset

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[datetime.date(2016, 1, 2),   datetime.date(2016, 5, 5)],

                       # case A->B, B->C, B->D => A->D
                       [datetime.date(2010, 2, 14),   datetime.date(2010, 3, 22)],
                       [datetime.date(2010, 3, 23),   datetime.date(2010, 4, 12)],
                       [datetime.date(2010, 3, 23),   datetime.date(2010, 5, 14)],
                       [datetime.date(2010, 5, 15),   datetime.date(2010, 6, 7)],
                       # -> 2010-02-14 | 2010-10-20

                       # case A->B, A->C, B->D => A->D
                       [datetime.date(2011, 1, 1),   datetime.date(2011, 2, 2)],
                       [datetime.date(2011, 1, 1),   datetime.date(2011, 3, 4)],
                       [datetime.date(2011, 2, 3),   datetime.date(2011, 4, 4)],
                       # -> 2011-01-01 | 2011-04-04

                       # case A->C, B->C, C->D => A->D
                       [datetime.date(2012, 5, 5),   datetime.date(2012, 6, 6)],
                       [datetime.date(2012, 5, 7),   datetime.date(2012, 6, 6)],
                       [datetime.date(2012, 6, 7),   datetime.date(2012, 12, 12)],
                       # -> 2012-05-05 | 2012-12-12

                       [datetime.date(2010, 6, 8),   datetime.date(2010, 10, 20)],
                       [datetime.date(2016, 5, 6),   datetime.date(2016, 10, 10)],
                       [datetime.date(2011, 1, 1),   datetime.date(9999, 12, 31)]],
                      columns=['start', 'end'])
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sort by starring dates? I recommend trying this: sort values in starring dates by their 4 letter. change them to integers, and then sort. Didn't tried but I guess it might help

Comment: Actually sorting ist the problem, i used this to sort them` recordsLst.sort(key=lambda x: x.start_dt, reverse=False)`, however this is not solving the groupping problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have to use the `Records`-class? If not, pandas offers a very clean implementation of what you are looking for:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[datetime.date(2017, 8, 14), datetime.date(2018, 3, 5)],
                    [datetime.date(2019, 1, 14), datetime.date(2019, 3, 6)],
                    [datetime.date(2019, 3, 7), datetime.date(2019, 3, 20)],
                    [datetime.date(2023, 12, 30), datetime.date(9999, 12, 31)],
                    [datetime.date(2020, 9, 8), datetime.date(2020, 9, 14)],
                    [datetime.date(2020, 9, 15), datetime.date(2020, 10, 14)],
                    [datetime.date(2019, 3, 21), datetime.date(2019, 3, 30)]],
                  columns=['start', 'end'])

df = df.sort_values('start').reset_index(drop=True)
mask = df['start'] - pd.to_timedelta('1 day') == df['end'].shift(1)
df.loc[mask.shift(-1).fillna(False), 'end'] = np.nan
df['end'] = df['end'].bfill()
df = df[~mask]
print(df)
```

And even if you have to use your class, you could just create it after you have done  the data handling in pandas by running:

```
resultLst  = df.apply(lambda x: Records(x['start'], x['end']), axis=1).tolist()
```

EDIT:

Unfortunately, it is not really easy to understand what your underlying rules are, but the following works out almost the same way as what you say:

```
df = df.groupby('end').min().reset_index() # If two end dates are identical, we keep the first?
df = df.sort_values('start').reset_index(drop=True)
df['start_reduced'] = df['start'] - pd.to_timedelta('1 day')
df['idx_orig'] = df.index
cols_to_drop = [x+'_y' for x in df.columns]
first_iter = True
seed_start_idx = []
while first_iter or mask.any():
    df = df.merge(df, how='left', left_on='end', right_on='start_reduced', suffixes=('', '_y'))
    mask = ~df['end_y'].isna()
    df.loc[mask, 'end'] = df.loc[mask, 'end_y'].values
    if first_iter:
        seed_start_idx = df.loc[~df['start'].isin(df.loc[mask, 'start_y']), 'idx_orig'].tolist()
    df = df.drop(columns=cols_to_drop)
    first_iter = False
df = df[df['idx_orig'].isin(seed_start_idx)].drop_duplicates(subset='idx_orig', keep='last').drop(columns=['start_reduced', 'idx_orig'])
```

The only difference is that it is not possible to distinguish which of the ones starting 2011-01-01 should be kept. You state that the one ending 2011-03-04 should not be kept, but the one ending 9999-12-31 should seemingly be kept. I cannot understand the logic behind that differentiation. The rest works though.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I have to use the Records class, since each object has other attributes which I did not post for simplicity's sake, however you are right i can pass them to pandas for pre-processing.
The approach works fine, however, when there are 2 simlar records it would not merge them. I edited the quetion with new dates and some rules to show what i mean.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I modified my answer with the new input

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need to take a closer look at how pandas work. The work you have done fits my case. Thanks again

Comment: Happy to help. But for your program, I would recommend that you really write out in prosa what you want to do and then translate this into code. Using examples always creates ambiguity. But my code should hopefully be sufficient to continue working once you come to the translation stage.